# Is let-in lazy in its bindings in Elm?

Tags: lazy-evaluation, elm, let

I have two features A and B that can either be both disabled, A enabled, B enabled, but not both enabled at the same time. After watching [Making Impossible States Impossible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcgmSRJHu_8) I wanted to try enforce this on the type level.

A simplified version of the solution I am considering is the following.

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)

type Model
  = NoneEnabled
  | AEnabled
  | BEnabled

init : Model
init = NoneEnabled

type Msg
  = EnableA
  | DisableA
  | EnableB
  | DisableB

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  let -- Buttons to enable and disable features
      buttons =
        div [] [ button [onClick EnableA] [text "Enable A"]
               , button [onClick DisableA] [text "Disable A"]
               , button [onClick EnableB] [text "Enable B"]
               , button [onClick DisableB] [text "Disable B"]
               ]

      -- All possible feature states
      aEnabled  = div [] [text "A enabled"]
      aDisabled = div [] [text "A disabled"]
      bEnabled  = div [] [text "B enabled"]
      bDisabled = div [] [text "B disabled"]
  in case model of
       NoneEnabled ->
         div [] [buttons, aDisabled, bDisabled]
       AEnabled ->
         div [] [buttons, aEnabled, bDisabled]
       BEnabled ->
         div [] [buttons, aDisabled, bEnabled]

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case (msg, model) of
    (EnableA, _) ->
      AEnabled
    (EnableB, _) ->
      BEnabled
    (DisableA, AEnabled) ->
      NoneEnabled
    (DisableB, BEnabled) ->
      NoneEnabled
    _ ->
      model

main : Program () Model Msg
main =
  Browser.sandbox { init = init, update = update, view = view }
```

My `aEnabled`, `aDisabled`, `bEnabled`, and `bDisabled` features in `view` are potentially expensive to compute. Will they be evaluated regardless of which branch `case model of` takes or can I rely on only the used features being evaluated?

Or phrased with a shorter example.

```
f c x =
  let a = x + 1
      b = x + 2
  in case c of
       True ->
         a
       False ->
         b
```

Will `f True 0` force the evaluation of `b` in the let expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Elm's `let`/`in` statements are not lazily evaluated. You can put some `Debug.log` statements to prove out the point:

```
f c x =
  let a = Debug.log "a calculated" <| x + 1
      b = Debug.log "b calculated" <| x + 2
  in case c of
       True ->
         a
       False ->
         b
```

Calling `f` just once will log both messages to the console, regardless of the input. [Example here](https://ellie-app.com/3z7zHw9Lh4Ya1).

One way to get around this hurdle is to require an arbitrary parameter for `a` and `b`, such as Unit `()`:

```
f c x =
  let a () = Debug.log "a calculated" <| x + 1
      b () = Debug.log "b calculated" <| x + 2
  in case c of
       True ->
         a ()
       False ->
         b ()
```

This variation will only evaluate the function `a` *or* `b`.

Comment: If I make `a` and `b` functions, will they be evaluated twice if used twice in the body or does Elm "de-duplicate" that?

Comment: There is no memoization, so the function would actually be called twice. [See this example](https://ellie-app.com/3GjhP8PPPKba1), which prints twice to the console when you call `a () + a ()`